# How path variable retain its old value after overwrite it

Tags: windows-10, command-line, environment-variables, path

the path command displays list of paths of executable files delimited by ; . I have tried to get help for command as follows

```
path --help
```

Later when I attempt to run commands like taskkill or ping, I got response as

```
'taskkil' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Then I realized I have overwritten the path variable. now path variable value is  "--help"

when I close and open another command prompt , now taskkill , ping commands are working. Also now path command displays same lists of paths that i have overwritten. How the path variable retains its values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start up a program such as your terminal your operating system creates an environment for your program.

As part of that environment it *copies* the current system environment into the programs environment.

Within that program any change to the path or other environment variables will only modify the environment *for that program*.

If you want to change the environment variables for the *system* then you should use the system provided methods for doing so. You will have to restart any programs you are using in order for them to "see" the new environment.

[What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)